# Finding a formula of a power of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Part of a solution I came across of calculating the following matrix:

$$\begin{pmatrix}\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} & -\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\\
\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} & \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}
\end{pmatrix}^n$$

I'm trying to find a formula for this matrix so I can prove it using induction. I tried to calculate $M^2,M^3,M^4$ but I can seem to see the pattern. How should I approach this issue?

Comment: Could you give us a bit more context here?  What class is this for?  Are you familiar with general linear-algebra techniques such as diagonalization?  Are you comfortable using complex numbers?

Answer (score 4):

It helps to interpret the matrix geometrically.  The matrix of a counterclockwise rotation about the origin by angle $\theta$ is given by
$$
R_\theta = \pmatrix{\cos \theta & -\sin \theta\\ \sin \theta & \cos \theta}
$$
Your matrix is simply $R_{45^\circ}$.  You should find, then, that $(R_{45^\circ})^n = R_{(45n)^\circ}$.

Comment: What is the order of $R_{45n}$ (when speaking of groups)?

Comment: $R_{45^\circ}$ has order $8$, so that should tell you everything you need to know

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

If you diagonalize and write $A = VDV^{-1}$ then $A^n = VD^n V^{-1}$.

Comment: can it be diagonalized? I get the characteristic polynomial: $p(\lambda)=\lambda^2-\sqrt{2} \lambda+1$.

Comment: @vesii - It can be diagonalized in $\Bbb C$ just fine. You will find that even though $V$ and $D$ are complex matrices, $A^n$ is real for all $n$.

Answer (score 0):

Idea
$$
\\\begin{pmatrix}\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} & -\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\\
\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} & \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1 & -1\\
1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}
\\\begin{pmatrix}1 & -1\\
1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}^n\cdot\Big(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\Big)^n=\begin{pmatrix}-i & i\\
1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}(1-i)^n & 0\\
0 & (1+i)^n
\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}-i & i\\
1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}^{-1}\cdot\frac{1}{2^{\frac n 2}}
$$

Comment: Yes I see it but using Wolfram ([link][1]) it gives me a matrix which is depend on $i$


  [1]: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B1,-1%7D,%7B1,1%7D%7D%5En

Comment: $(\cos\phi+i\cdot\sin\phi)^n=\cos(n\cdot\phi)+i\cdot\sin(n\cdot\phi)$